# Java Stream API how to improve expression

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
public List<Entry> getEntriesForUserId(int userId) {
    User u = DataBaseConnector
        .getAllUsers()
        .stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getUserId() == userId)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(new User(-1, "Error");
    return u.getEntries();
}
```

`getEntries()` returns a `List<Entry>`.

How can I add the return statement into this lambda expression? Something like 
`.map(User::getEntries)`?

Comment: I know I'm sidestepping the question, but are you simply going to ignore the error condition and return an empty list or null for unknown user id's? That's quite bad practise (as is also the use of -1 user id as an error message). If possible, you should redesign the method contract to allow error reporting.

Comment: return streamOperationsChain(...).map(Class::member).orElseGet(() -> alternate);

Comment: @Torben this is just my MVCE example. The original implementation throws an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Your code won't compile, there is a typo: a parenthese is missing at then end of `.orElse(new User(-1, "Error")`

Comment: I just typed a MVCE here

Comment: Fine for me then :) It's just that all answers have reported the typo. But your MVCE is still good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need lambda to return the list, you can just say:

```
public List<Entry> getEntriesForUserId(int userId) {
    return DataBaseConnector
             .getAllUsers()
             .stream()
             .filter(user -> user.getUserId() == userId)
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(new User(-1, "Error")
             .getEntries();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here already, but let me add one more thing - remember to use `orElseGet` instead of `orElse` in such cases. It will not create `User` eagerly:

```
.orElseGet(() -> new User(-1, "Error")
```

Comment: A good hint. However, isn't it called immediately upon the method call anyway?

Comment: @Nikolas it will be called only when findFirst() returns an empty Optional, otherwise, the object will be created always

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. (Your name is impossible to type correctly). :))

Answer (score 2):

Since the entire Stream method chain returns a single `User u` and then you call `return u.getEntries();`, feel free to append the second line to the end of Stream and return it as is:

```
return DataBaseConnector.getAllUsers().stream()
                                      .filter(user -> user.getUserId() == userId)
                                      .findFirst()
                                      .orElse(new User(-1, "Error"))
                                      .getEntries();
```

Comment: This is duplicate answer from `@S.K`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik: I don't look usually at other answers when I post mine since I have no time while typing mine. Moreover, this one is that obvious that needs to be copied?

Comment: yes, anyway after post it you should remove it, because you were not the first.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik: My answer is more informative. Explains WHY.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Just leave the "mine is bigger" attitude to Nikolas, and upvote the other answer... You can as well downvote this answer if you think that it does not add anything useful.

Comment: StackOverflow should not be about answering first. Instead a quality question deserves a quality answer.

Comment: @Florian Albeigch: That's right attitude. @oleg.cherednik: Note that I explain why it's not needed to use `Stream::map` since the entire Stream returns a single `User` and not `List<User>`, thus no `map` is needed.

Comment: @Nikolas really, I don't care, sorry. I just wanted to help oleg to find a better way to deal with the situation.